# What does '/' mean in python docs

Tags: python, doc

For example

`seek(cookie, whence=0, /)`method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance.

What does '/' mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Where do you see that?

Comment: It's an error. Here is the correct documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek